# Java Fx 2: Refresh item color in ListView

Tags: listview, cell, javafx-2

Help! I can't figure this one out. I'm trying to make a ListView where the color of the text item changes when the user clicks on it. The same way hyperlinks indicate if they have been visited.

I wrote a custom Cell Factory that does this, the problem is that the Cell factory is not being called when I click on an item.

I tried to work around this by actually changing the VALUE of the item in order to get the cell factory to be called, however, here's the problem: if I change the VALUE from within the ChangeListener which I set up to monitor if a user clicks on a new item, it's going to call my ChangeListener AGAIN, and then it becomes an infinite loop. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add mouse listener to your cell factory and change color from it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I also found a workaround. I added a global boolean that changes the way my ChangeListener executes. If it's true, it does nothing buts sets the boolean to false. So i set the boolean to true, then I change the value of my cell to a temporary value in order to force the redraw, this runs my changelistener again, but this time it does nothing but sets the boolean back to false. Then I set it to true again, and change the value back from the temporary to the original. This runs it a third time, doing nothing again but setting it back to false.